# Tabulator Data Save Event

Tags: ajax, events, save, tabulator

Does anyone know if there is a Tabulator save event?

Problem:
A user makes changes in a Tabulator cell. The update is persisted in the database and affects the other rows in the Tabulator. I'd like to be able to update the other Tabulator rows. However, in order to do this, I need to know that the data was successfully stored in the database. Is there any Tabulator event to do this? I'm looking for something similar to an Ajax success callback.

Thanks

I have tried several Tabulator events but none of them provide the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator has no concept of saving. This is because every application saves differently, and as a result of a different action so there is no point building it directly into the library.

You should decide when you want to save the table (for example when a user finished editing a cell) and then use the appropriate event to trigger your save action.

A full list of table events can be found here: https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/events